# Forcing in GBC, the ctm approach

Tags: set-theory, forcing

There is a nice, detailed survey about forcing in GBC in the appendix of the dissertation of Jonas Reitz. At page 115 the author wrote: " If $ \Gamma $
is a finite collection of sentences forced by $ \mathbb{P} $, then I require only a finite
portion of BGC in the ground model for the forcing argument to be carried
out." I am a little bit confused here. Since GBC is finitely axiomatizable this finite portion can be the whole GBC isn't it? But if it is, then we can not prove the existence a countable transitive (or any) model of $\Gamma $ (unless GBC is inconsistent)  which makes for me unclear the further arguments.

Comment: What if we define that a "finite" fragment of GBC asserts the existence of all $\Sigma_n$-definable (with class parameters) classes for some fixed $n$? You can certainly get set models of this theory and you should be able to argue that for any finite collection of sentences forced by $\mathbb P$ this much of the theory suffices.

Comment: I wonder if perhaps Jonas was only concerned with first-order sentences in $\Gamma$, in which case he might really mean that he needs only finitely much of ZFC to get them, and then the reflection theorem applies and so on.  By the way, one can find his dissertation here: http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0609064.

Comment: David, thanks for the question! And Vika and Joel, your comments are much appreciated.  I believe I had something sensible in mind, but it was not what I wrote - I suspect that Joel's comment is on point.  I won't be in a position to give this proper thought for some time, so other responses are most welcome.

Comment: Could you explain your idea about using $\Sigma_n$-definable classes in more detail? If we are allowed to use class parameters in definitions, then we are able to define any classes by a formula like x=p aren't we?